# Eclipse RCP: How can I manage Back Forward actions?

Tags: eclipse-rcp

In my RCP application, the back and forward buttons work strangely. They do not navigate to correct editor view as I expected. How or where can I configure back and forward action?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please see similar question, hope it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10417009/use-navigation-history-in-eclipse-rcp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the eclipse article about navigation history: http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_hook_my_editor_to_the_Back_and_Forward_buttons%3F